# How to restrict the maximum size of an element in a list in Python?

Tags: python

Problem Statement:
There are 5 sockets and 6 phones. Each phone takes 60 minutes to charge completely. What is the least time required to charge all phones?
The phones can be interchanged along the sockets

What I've tried:
I've made a list with 6 elements whose initial value is 0. I've defined two functions. Switch function, which interchanges the phone one socket to the left. Charge function, which adds value 10(charging time assumed) to each element, except the last (as there are only 5 sockets). As the program proceeds, how do I restrict individual elements to 60, while other lower value elements still get added 10 until they attain the value of 60?

Comment: can't this be done here, if list element value gets greater than 60, limit to 60 considering you're modifying single element at a time.

Comment: `element = min(element + 10, 60)`

Comment: Try using an `if` conditional. Assuming you're iterating over the phones in a for loop with a local index variable `i`, then it could be something like `if phone_charge[i] == 60: # do nothing; else: phone_charge[i] += 10`

Answer (score 1):

Charging is freely interchangeable, so this is a trivial algebra problem.

```
6 * 60 charger minutes / 5 chargers = 72 minutes clock time to charge.
```

Each phone needs to be on some charger for 60 minutes total, and off for 12 minutes.  The rota is simple, but your 10-minute quanta will fail to find the solution.

Put 5 phones on the 5 chargers.  Every 12 minutes, swap out one phone that has been charging since the start, and swap in the idle phone.  This solution is extensible for any quantity of phones and chargers.

Answer (score 0):

In the charge function, add an if condition that checks the value of the element.
I'm not sure what you're add function looks like exactly, but I would define the pseudocode to look something like this:

if element < 60:

add 10 to the element

This way, if an element is greater than or equal to 60, it won't get caught by the if condition and won't get anything added to it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply restrict the maximum element size. What you can do is check the element size with a if condition and terminate the process.

btw, answer is 6x60/5=72 mins.

Comment: sry, mistake, i have changed. it is 72 mins.